# How to keep local topic (feature) branches from being pushed to the remote

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

Suppose I pull a branch `develop` from a remote repo and create a local branch `feature_xxx` to work on some feature

```
A---B---C---D    develop
     \
      X          feature_xxx
```

I make some commits to the `feature_xxx` branch and merge it back to the local `develop` branch.

```
A---B---C---D---E  develop
     \         /
      X---Y---Z    feature_xxx
```

Finally I push the `develop` branch back to the remote repo

```
git push my_remote develop
```

The problem is that all the commits get pushed to the remote, including the X, Y, Z commits, so the branches on the remote now look like this:

```
A---B---C---D---E  develop
     \         /
      X---Y---Z
```

Actually I used those X, Y, Z commits during development and do not want them to show up on the remote. I'd like the branch on the remote to be like this:

```
A---B---C---D---E  develop
```

I suppose there are several ways to achieve this in Git, but which solution would be the simplest?

Comment: rebase or merge with squash. I prefer to keep the separate history, and encourage junior developers especially to push changes to the server regularly to be able to see progress and perhaps help them change direction during their development.

Comment: Regroup your commits `X - Y - Z` into one (using `git reset --soft @~3`) on your `feature-xxx` branch and create a commit X. Then, merge it in `develop`. You have now only one commit (plus an hypothetical merge commit)

Answer (score 1):

The simpler short-hand for the rebase operation that others are outlining, if you really just want *one* commit to represent all the work from the branch, is to use the `--squash` option to `git merge`:

```
git checkout develop
git merge --squash feature_xxx
```

This leaves you with

```
A---B---C---D---XYZ  develop
 \         
  X---Y---Z    feature_xxx
```

where XYZ is a single commit.  You can then delete the `feature_xxx` branch.

As an aside - just a matter of terminology, but worth keeping straight in my opinion:  Even with your original approach, you were *not* pushing the `feature_xxx` branch.  In git a branch is not a line of commits; a branch is a ref, which is a pointer to the tip commit and nothing more.

So really your question, in git terms, was not how to avoid pushing the branch. It was how to represent the changes from the branch as if the changes had been made in a single, normal commit directly on develop.

While it's a matter of opinion and circumstance, I usually prefer to keep the topology of feature branches myself.  When I ask people why they think a `--squash`ed merge is "cleaner", usually it ends up being about `log` output.  But if you put a good commit message on a merge, you can get linear `log` output simply by passing `--first-parent` to the `log` command, without the need to use revisionist history like `--squash` merges.

Comment: `as if the changes had been made in a single, normal commit directly on develop` ... this is _exactly_ what a rebase workflow is intended for.

Comment: Unfortunately in my example the rebase workflow forces me to expose all the intermediate commits (X, Y, Z in the example) that are often not needed on the remote. I my case only the final (E) commit is valuable for other developers.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - No, it is *one* of the things rebase can be made to do.  But it is *exactly* what the `--squash` argument to `merge` is intended for, and that is why - as can be seen from the various answers - a squash merge performs the task more easily.

Comment: @mquinn - the `rebase` workflow can be made to provide only the one commit, if you set it up to squash the other commits. Done the right way it would be exactly equivalent to the approach I describe (but more work)

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to rebase `feature_xxx` on `develop`, and then to fast-forward the `develop` branch with your work from the feature branch.

**Before:**

```
develop ... A---B---C---D
             \
feature       X---Y---Z
```

Now do the following:

```
git checkout feature_xxx
git rebase develop
```

This will leave you with the following diagram:

```
develop ... A---B---C---D
                         \
feature                   X'---Y'---Z'
```

Now you can *fast-forward* the `develop` branch with your changes from the feature branch:

```
git checkout develop
git merge feature_xxx
```

This leaves you with *both* the `develop` *and* `feature_xxx` branches looking the same:

```
develop ... A---B---C---D---X'---Y'---Z' feature
```

In other words, your history appears that you did all your work right on top of `develop`.  You may have to still do a merge, but the work you have done is linear, and there should be no merge commits from the work itself.

Comment: That it a good solution but is it possible not to use the rebase approach? I'd like to keep the local history the way it is, that is keep the `feature_xxx` branch separate from the `develop` branch to make it easily distinguishable.

Comment: @mquinn - All the more reason to just do a merge; if the distinguishable `feature_xxx` branch is of value to you, it's probably of value to your collaborators.  But, see my answer for a way to do what you want.  (Technically you can do what you want even with `rebase`, but it's just extra commands for extra commands' sake at that point.)

Answer (score 0):

When you are at this stage

```
A---B---C---D    develop
 \
  X--Y--Z          feature_xxx
```

Instead of merging feature back to develop, while you are still on the feature branch, you can do a rebase `git rebase develop`, then you can go back to develop and `git merge feature` to fast forward the pointer of develop branch to the same place with feature branch, then your repository should look like this:

```
  A---B---C---D--X--Y--Z        both develop & feature_xxx are pointing at Z
```

If you don't want so many commits, you can squash them by using `git rebase -i SHA1-of-the-commit-you-wanna-go-back-to`

At this point, you will see the following message from the command line

```
pick 4b33d01 some commit message for X
pick 61516e4 some commit message for Y
pick e0311e2 some commit message for Z
```

Just change the action of commits that you want to squash from "pick" to "s" for squash, like this

```
pick 4b33d01 some commit message for X
s 61516e4 some commit message for Y
s e0311e2 some commit message for Z
```

Last step: `!wq`, you are good to go.

Comment: I hope it is possible not to use the rebase approach (as I have commented below).